# extract subtree containing key NewtonSoft JSon

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a heavily nested JSON and when I get a search term, I search in the JSON for the key and get a sub-JSON which has the key and all its parent. Something like this:

```
{
    "Name": "Torr",
    "Attr1": {
        "A": 1,
        "Attr1_1": {
            "A": 1
        },
        "Attr1_2" :{
            "B": 1
        },
    },
    "A": 2
}
```

and searching for A should give me

```
{
    "Attr1": {
        "A": 1,
        "Attr1_1": {
            "A": 1
        },
    },
    "A": 2
}
```

I'm using NewtonSoft.Json and having this JSON as a JToken. Can this be done or is there any searching algorithm which can be implemented to get this ?

Comment: It is hard to understand what do you want . Show the bigger json to see what is the difference between trees

Comment: I need to construct a sub tree, where only the search term and its parent must be present.

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement this algorithm .. calling it with the root node would filter the tree recursively leaving only searchKey elements and their ancestors

```
//returns true if the passed node should stay in the tree, and false otherwise
bool filterTree(node) {
    bool existChildrenWithKey = false;
    foreach(child in node.children){
        bool toBeRemoved =  !filterTree(child);
        existChildrenWithKey|= !toBeRemoved;
        if(toBeRemoved) node.RemoveChild(child);
    }   
    return existChildrenWithKey || node.key==searchKey  ;
}
```